# How do I remove myself from this workplace exchange?

Tags: discussion

This is not my community.  I posted something thoughtful and prescient and got a -6 and someone locked the page for "low quality spam answers".  I will stick to stack exchange I think.

Can anyone tell me how to take it off my profile?  Or an admin do it?

Comment: I don't know about taking it off, but you could just ignore it and move on.  PS: If it was locked for spam answers, that's not really a judgement of your question so much as a judgement of the community's response to it.  Downvotes are used to indicate when a question could be improved, it doesn't mean they hate your question or you for asking it. Ideally, downvoters should be leaving comments to explain what they think needs improvement.  If they didn't do that in your case, I apologize for the negative experience.

Comment: There's a "contact" link in the footer. One of the options in the page is that you wish to delete your user here.

Comment: @Steve-O Have you read [the answer in question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/96904)?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [What are the best ways to keep controversial topics from getting heated](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/what-are-the-best-ways-to-keep-controversial-topics-from-getting-heated/4693#4693) - I think a different phrasing of your opinion might've made a big difference in how it was received.

Comment: see [Remove account on a single Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235301/165773)

Comment: The page wasn't locked, it was protected and it's bound to happen when a question gets a lot of answers. It wasn't directly because of what you wrote, i assure you.  It just means that a person needs a little more reputation to add an answer to that question.  I would encourage you to stick around and participate and your reputation will rise organically so protection wouldn't affect you anyway.  As for the downvotes, don't let it bother you. Literally every single person who participates here gets downvotes from time to time.  You can't make everyone happy,  Try not to take it personally.

Answer (score 1):

From [How do I disassociate a question with my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285385/255187) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (Even though the question is about questions, the answer also applies to answers):

> Use the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the site and be sure to include a link to your post. A post can be disassociated by request of the author, but a disassociation can only be performed by an employee of Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can also disassociate an entire site from your account as well as deleting your entire account - it seems that OP is trying to do one of those things, not just disassociate a single post.

Comment: @Dukeling except in extraordinary circumstances, you can't disconnect one of your accounts from the rest -- that requires direct database edits by employees.  You can *hide* an account -- not foolproof, but it deflects casual observers.